# delete the specific value from specific column from matlab

Tags: database, matlab

I want to delete specific values/data from one column with the WHERE condition. I used this code:

```
A ='ab123';
sqlquery = ['DELETE * FROM myTable WHERE ' ...
                'product = ' A];
curs = exec(conn,sqlquery);
curs = fetch(curs);
```

but nothing changed.

is there another way to delete it.... thank you in advance

Comment: Do U want to delete the whole row or replace the column value to a empty string

Comment: Did you do `close(curs)`? There might be a transaction open?